# How does Windows know which network adapter is a wireless device?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, wireless-networking, windows-registry, wmi

I'm trying and trying to find a value in the registry or through WMI (with wbemtest) which tells me that this network adapter uses a wireless connection.
There are values in the WMI Win32_NetworkAdapter class like AdapterType but they are only telling me that it is a Ethernet device. On another pc when I query this class then I get a WiFi_NetworkAdapter entry but I think that depends on how the driver vendor has implemented it.
I even tried to find something in the registry but couldn't find anything. The only part where I can see that this is a wireless device is when I am looking at the name and description but to be honest that is not a good solution.
On Windows XP I found a registry key with a "MediaSubType" field under

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\{GUID}\Connection`

but on Windows 7 this key seems not to be obligatory.

Any other solution besides Registry or WMI is also very appreciated but please keep in mind that I don't wanna use third party tools because later on I want to write a little C++ program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `MediaSubType` DWORD value. If MediaSubtype = 2 then network adapter is a wireless device.

```
powershell gci 'hklm:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}' -rec ^| gp ^| FT MediaSubtype, Name, PnpInstanceID -Au
```

Or get [_MIB_IF_ROW2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, see NDIS_PHYSICAL_MEDIUM.

Also may use PnpInstanceID and [PCI ID Repository (database)](http://pciids.sourceforge.net/) or [PCI Vendor and Device Lists (info)](http://www.pcidatabase.com/).

Get list of all our wireless connections and their signal strengths:

```
wmic /NAMESPACE:\\ROOT\wmi path MSNdis_80211_ReceivedSignalStrength get *
```

Comment: I think I will use the MIB_IF_ROW because the MIB_IF_ROW2 is only supported since Vista, right? But yes ... that was is what I've needed.

Comment: @SeveFriede Then if I forgot it all depends on the version of NDIS driver. I could be wrong, check the information on the MSDN CD.

Comment: Thank you STTR! I think in my C++ code I will go for this [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx) and this should work fine on Windows XP with SP1 and later (:

Comment: @SeveFriede `wmic nicconfig get MACAddress, IPAddress, Index, ServiceName, Description` - get IP address, MAC ... etc)

Comment: but MSNdis_80211_ReceivedSignalStrength is only working when a WiFi is connected to a network, right?

Comment: @SeveFriede If WiFi adapter switches on. Optional WiFi connected to a network.